# Creating and Merging Multiple Datasets Does Not Fit Into Memory, Use Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question, but I need some clarification on how to make use of Dask's ability to "handle datasets that don't fit into memory", because I'm a little confused on how it works from the CREATION of these datasets.

I have made a reproducible code below that closely emulates my problem. Although this example DOES fit into my 16Gb memory, we can assume that it doesn't because it does take up ALMOST all of my RAM.

I'm working with 1min, 5min, 15min and Daily stock market datasets, all of which have their own technical indicators, so each of these separate dataframes are 234 columns in width, with the 1min dataset having the most rows (521,811), and going down from there. Each of these datasets can be created and fit into memory on their own, but here's where it gets tricky.

I'm trying to merge them column-wise into 1 dataframe, each column prepended with their respective timeframes so I can tell them apart, but this creates the memory problem. This is what I'm looking to accomplish visually:

[image: DesiredOutcome]

I'm not really sure if Dask is what I need here, but I assume so. I'm NOT looking to use any kind of "parallel calculations" here (yet), I just need a way to create this dataframe before feeding it into a machine learning pipeline (yes, I know it's a stock market problem, just overlook that for now). I know Dask has a machine learning pipeline I can use, so maybe I'll make use of that in the future, however I need a way to save this big dataframe to disk, or create it upon importing it on the fly.

What I need help with is how to do this. Seeing as each of these datasets on their own fit into memory nicely, an idea I had (and this may not be correct at all so please let me know), would be to save each of the dataframes to separate parquet files to disk, then create a Dask dataframe object to import each of them into, when I go to start the machine learning pipeline. Something like this:

[image: Idea1]

Is this conceptually correct with what I need to do, or am I way off? haha. I've read through the documentation on Dask, and also checked out [this guide](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/10-minutes-to-dask.html) specifically, which is good, however as a newbie I need some guidance with how to do this for the first time.

How can I create and save this big merged dataframe to disk, if I can't create it in memory in the first place?

Here is my reproducible dataframe/memory problem code. Be careful when you go to run this as it'll eat up your RAM pretty quickly, I have 16Gb of RAM and it does run on my fairly light machine, but not without some red-lining RAM, just wanted to give the Dask gods out there something specific to work with. Thanks!

```
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, merge
from numpy import random

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                         1 MINUTE DATASET                                         #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS = 521811
ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS = 234
main_df = DataFrame(random.randint(0,100, size=(ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS, ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS)), 
                    columns=list("col_" + str(x) for x in range(ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS)),
                    index=date_range(start="2019-12-09 04:00:00", freq="min", periods=ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS))


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                         5 MINUTE DATASET                                         #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
FIVE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS = 117732
FIVE_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS = 234
five_min_df = DataFrame(random.randint(0,100, size=(FIVE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS, FIVE_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS)), 
                    columns=list("5_min_col_" + str(x) for x in range(FIVE_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS)),
                    index=date_range(start="2019-12-09 04:00:00", freq="5min", periods=FIVE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS))
# Merge the 5 minute to the 1 minute df
main_df = merge(main_df, five_min_df, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True, sort=True)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                         15 MINUTE DATASET                                        #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS = 117732
FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS = 234
fifteen_min_df = DataFrame(random.randint(0,100, size=(FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS, FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS)), 
                    columns=list("15_min_col_" + str(x) for x in range(FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_COLS)),
                    index=date_range(start="2019-12-09 04:00:00", freq="15min", periods=FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS))
# Merge the 15 minute to the main df
main_df = merge(main_df, fifteen_min_df, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True, sort=True)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                           DAILY DATASET                                          #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
DAILY_NUM_OF_ROWS = 933
DAILY_NUM_OF_COLS = 234
fifteen_min_df = DataFrame(random.randint(0,100, size=(DAILY_NUM_OF_ROWS, DAILY_NUM_OF_COLS)), 
                    columns=list("daily_col_" + str(x) for x in range(DAILY_NUM_OF_COLS)),
                    index=date_range(start="2019-12-09 04:00:00", freq="D", periods=DAILY_NUM_OF_ROWS))
# Merge the daily to the main df (don't worry about "forward peaking" dates)
main_df = merge(main_df, fifteen_min_df, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True, sort=True)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                            FFILL NAN's                                           #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
main_df = main_df.fillna(method="ffill")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                              INSPECT                                             #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
print(main_df)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the top answer below, I'm getting closer to my solution.

I've fixed a few syntax errors in the code, and have a working example, UP TO the daily timeframe. When I use the `1B` timeframe for upsampling to business days, the error is:

`ValueError: <BusinessDay> is a non-fixed frequency`

I think it has something to do with this line:

`data_index = higher_resolution_index.floor(data_freq).drop_duplicates()`

...as that's what I see in the traceback. I don't think Pandas likes the `1B` timeframe and the `floor()` function, so is there an alternative?

I need to have daily data in there too, however the code works for every other timeframe. Once I can get this daily thing figured out, I'll be able to apply it to my use case.

Thanks!

```
from pandas import DataFrame, concat, date_range
from numpy import random
import dask.dataframe as dd, dask.delayed

ROW_CHUNK_SIZE = 5000

def load_data_subset(start_date, freq, data_freq, hf_periods):
    higher_resolution_index = date_range(start_date, freq=freq, periods=hf_periods)
    data_index = higher_resolution_index.floor(data_freq).drop_duplicates()
    dummy_response = DataFrame(
        random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(data_index), 234)),
        columns=list(
            f"{data_freq}_col_" + str(x) for x in range(234)
        ),
        index=data_index
    )
    dummy_response = dummy_response.loc[higher_resolution_index.floor(data_freq)].set_axis(higher_resolution_index)
    return dummy_response

@dask.delayed
def load_all_columns_for_subset(start_date, freq, hf_periods):
    return concat(
        [
            load_data_subset(start_date, freq, "1min", hf_periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, freq, "5min", hf_periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, freq, "15min", hf_periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, freq, "1H", hf_periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, freq, "4H", hf_periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, freq, "1B", hf_periods),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )

ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS = 521811
full_index = date_range(
    start="2019-12-09 04:00:00",
    freq="1min",
    periods=ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS,
)

df = dask.dataframe.from_delayed([load_all_columns_for_subset(full_index[i], freq="1min", hf_periods=ROW_CHUNK_SIZE) for i in range(0, ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS, ROW_CHUNK_SIZE)])

# Save df to parquet here when ready
```

Comment: actually - I just gave your question another read through. I'm not totally sure what you're hoping to achieve by merging dataframes with different frequencies column-wise. this will work the same way in dask.dataframe as it will in pandas - if you do this the daily dataset will have 1 row with data for every 5759 rows of NaNs. same for the 1-minute, but 86399:1 in that case. if that's what you are hoping for then this will work, but just flagging that in case it wasn't clear. but there may be more efficient ways to approach the problem?

Comment: Yes, the daily’s will have NaNs which is fine, I’ll be forward filling the nans. Essentially, every row will represent the current minute, plus the most recent 5minute, 15minute, daily data as well. It’s like looking at 4 different charts at the same time. So I do want them merged together like described. I’m constructing these dataframes individually, but it just chews up my ram before I have a chance to save the merged dataframe. Most of the tut’s deal with importing an already saved datasets in chunks, but I’m trying to create it in the first place…

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I took a stab at a solution (which I know is incorrect lol) and posted it above with some more direction into what I'm looking to accomplish. Feel free to take a look at it and let me know what I need to do.

Comment: since you know ahead of time how the indices will join, I'd create the lower-frequency datasets with the index of the higher frequency data explicitly. you can still create the data partition-by-partition, you just have to do a bit more legwork. in other words, don't use merge. it will kill you here. make sure your indices and partiitons line up exactly between the dataframes, and if you really want your data structured like this, maybe create the whole dataframe at once (all columns, but still partitioned chunk by chunk).

Comment: Thanks! I think I get what you mean, create all columns and 1minute index first, and start with the daily, then work backwards to 1 minute, and chunk the rows. I'll give er a shot! Thanks

Comment: it looks like in your update, you're still trying to merge the dataframes. I really don't think you should do this. I think you should build a pipeline for each frequency which can be called with an arbitrary date range, as I have in my answer, and return a single partition. Then bundle these into a single partition-wise workflow that builds all columns for a subset of rows, which can be applied as a delayed op to all partitions. This way, you can build the dataframe iteratively as you move row-wise (not column-wise) through the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take the [dask.dataframe tutorial](https://tutorial.dask.org/04_dataframe.html) and look at the [dataframe best practices guide](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html). dask can work with larger-than-memory datasets generally by one of two approaches:

1. design your job ahead of time, then iterate through partitions of the data,  writing the outputs as you go, so that not all of the data is in memory at the same time.
2. use a distributed cluster to leverage more (distributed) memory than exists on any one machine.

It sounds like you're looking for approach (1). The actual implementation will depend on how you access/generate the data, but generally I'd say you should not think of the job as "generate the larger-than-memory dataset in memory then dump it into the dask dataframe". Instead, you'll need to think carefully about how to load the data partition-by-partition, so that each partition can work independently.

Modifying your example, the full workflow might look something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, dask.dataframe, dask.delayed

@dask.delayed
def load_data_subset(start_date, freq, periods):
    # presumably, you'd query some API or something here
    dummy_ind = pd.date_range(start_date, freq=freq, periods=periods)
    dummy_response = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(dummy_ind), 234)),
        columns=list("daily_col_" + str(x) for x in range(234)),
        index=dummy_ind
    )
    return dummy_response

# generate a partitioned dataset with a configurable frequency, with each dataframe having a consistent number of rows.
FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS = 117732
full_index = pd.date_range(
    start="2019-12-09 04:00:00",
    freq="15min",
    periods=FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS,
)
df_15min = dask.dataframe.from_delayed([
    load_data_subset(full_index[i], freq="15min", periods=10000)
    for i in range(0, FIFTEEN_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS, 10000)
])
```

You could now write these to disk, concat, etc, and at any given point, each dask worker will only be working with 10,000 rows at a time. Ideally, you'll design the chunks so each partition will have a couple hundred MBs each - see the best practices section on [partition sizing](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-partitions).

This could be extended to include multiple frequencies like this:

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, dask.dataframe, dask.delayed

def load_data_subset(start_date, freq, data_freq, hf_periods):
    # here's your 1min time series *for this partition*
    high_res_ind = pd.date_range(start_date, freq=freq, periods=hf_periods)
    # here's your lower frequency (e.g. 1H, 1day) index 
    # for the same period
    data_ind = high_res_ind.floor(data_freq).drop_duplicates()

    # presumably, you'd query some API or something here. 
    # Alternatively, you could read subsets of your pre-generated 
    # frequency files. this covers the same dates as the 1 minute 
    # dataset, but only has the number of periods in the lower-res
    # time series
    dummy_response = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(len(data_ind), 234)),
        columns=list(
            f"{data_freq}_col_" + str(x) for x in range(234)
        ),
        index=data_ind
    )

    # now, reindex to the shape of the new data (this does the
    # forward fill step):
    dummy_response = (
        dummy_response
        .loc[high_res_ind.floor(data_freq)]
        .set_axis(high_res_ind)
    )

    return dummy_response

@dask.delayed
def load_all_columns_for_subset(start_date, periods):
    return pd.concat(
        [
            load_data_subset(start_date, "1min", "1min", periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, "1min", "5min", periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, "1min", "15min", periods),
            load_data_subset(start_date, "1min", "D", periods),
        ],
        axis=1,
    )

# generate a partitioned dataset with all columns, where lower 
# frequency columns have been ffilled, with each dataframe having
# a consistent number of rows.
ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS = 521811
full_index = pd.date_range(
    start="2019-12-09 04:00:00",
    freq="1min",
    periods=ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS,
)
df_full = dask.dataframe.from_delayed([
    load_all_columns_for_subset(full_index[i], periods=10000)
    for i in range(0, ONE_MIN_NUM_OF_ROWS, 10000)
])
```

This runs straight through for me. It also exports the full dataframe just fine if you call `df_full.to_parquet(filepath)` right after this. I ran this with a `dask.distributed` scheduler (running on my laptop) and kept an eye on the dashboard and total memory never exceeded 3.5GB.

Because there are so many columns the dask.dataframe preview is a bit unweildy, but here's the head and tail:

```py
In [10]: df_full.head()
Out[10]:
                     1min_col_0  1min_col_1  1min_col_2  1min_col_3  1min_col_4  1min_col_5  1min_col_6  1min_col_7  ...  D_col_226  D_col_227  D_col_228  D_col_229  D_col_230  D_col_231  D_col_232  D_col_233
2019-12-09 04:00:00          88          36          34          57          54          98           4          92  ...         84          3         49         29         62         47         21         21
2019-12-09 04:01:00          89          61          50           2          73          44          49          33  ...         84          3         49         29         62         47         21         21
2019-12-09 04:02:00           9          18          73          76          28          17          10          49  ...         84          3         49         29         62         47         21         21
2019-12-09 04:03:00          59          73          92          28          32           8          24          85  ...         84          3         49         29         62         47         21         21
2019-12-09 04:04:00          40          54          23           5          52          63          61          64  ...         84          3         49         29         62         47         21         21

[5 rows x 936 columns]

In [11]: df_full.tail()
Out[11]:
                     1min_col_0  1min_col_1  1min_col_2  1min_col_3  1min_col_4  1min_col_5  1min_col_6  1min_col_7  ...  D_col_226  D_col_227  D_col_228  D_col_229  D_col_230  D_col_231  D_col_232  D_col_233
2020-12-11 05:15:00          81           8          51           2          77          26          66          23  ...         15         51         66         26         88         85         91         65
2020-12-11 05:16:00          67          68          34          58          43          40          76          72  ...         15         51         66         26         88         85         91         65
2020-12-11 05:17:00          93          66          21          39          12          96          53           4  ...         15         51         66         26         88         85         91         65
2020-12-11 05:18:00          69           9          69          41           5           6           6          37  ...         15         51         66         26         88         85         91         65
2020-12-11 05:19:00          18          50          25          74          78          51          10          83  ...         15         51         66         26         88         85         91         65

[5 rows x 936 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear direction, example, and resources for me to check out. I'll be able to figure this out now. Thanks!!!

Comment: @MattWilson updated to include a full walkthrough

Comment: Just getting around to testing the code you provided now. The solution you provided is throwing an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'`. Also there's a bunch of `Referenced before assignments` on the `hf_periods` variables. Can you look into this, and also run the code from start to finish so I can see the output'd df? It should match what I'm looking for in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: I have fixed the errors I just mentioned, but am now stuck. See my edited `UPDATE` above. Thanks!

Comment: hey sorry about the typos. fixed. this runs straight through for me.

Comment: for the 1B question I think that could go in another question - we're pretty far beyond the scope for a single question here, and for something straightforward like that you could ask a targeted question about rounding datetimes to 1 business day and get advice from pandas experts :)